# why <?php wp_title(); ?> adds '»' symbol?

Tags: theme-development, wp-title

on last Wordpress when I wrote `<?php wp_title(); ?>`  appear » symbol before the name of the page..

On my `functions.php` I wrote `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );`

Thanks

Comment: the symbol comes from the function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/

Answer (score 0):

The [`wp_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/) function is meant to be used in things like breadcrumbs where  you would want something like `My Blog » My Category » My Post`. As such the function allows you to prepend something to your title. By default it prepends ». If you just want the title of your post or page use [`the_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/).